# InDesign - force table column width

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm using **InDesign** scripts in order to process .docx documents. I'm experiencing some issues with **tables**. Is there any way to force the columns's width value?
So far, I've tried this to no avail:

```
var myAdjustment = myParentWidth / myTableWidth;
currentTable.columns[c].width = myTableColWidths[c] * myAdjustment;
currentTable.columns[c].recompose();
```

This works fine as long as there are no long words placed within the cells, otherwise the width adjust has no effect whatsoever. I don't care whether the words are correctly broken or not (hyphenation), I just want the table to fit inside my frame.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if relaxing the hyphenation rules for those cells would help?

Comment: I have defined no hyphenation rules so far. How can I do what you're saying?